# SML : drop the first n elements of a list

Tags: sml, smlnj

So, I know there is a build in function to drop elements but it works if you wish to drop the last n elements.
I want to drop the first n elements.
An example:

```
  > drop([1,2,3,4], 2)   
    > [1,2]
```

I've wrote this piece of code:

```
exception Subscription;

val counter = 0;

fun drop (l,0) = l 
| drop([], n) = raise Subscription
| drop(h::x, n) = if n<0 then raise Subscription
 else if(counter <n) then  
     let 
         val counter = counter +1
     in 
         (h:: drop(x,n))
     end    
 else nil
 ;    


drop([1,2,3,4],2);
```

it won't be compiled.  The error message I get is :

```
   uncaught exception Subscription
    raised at: dropper.ml:6.23-6.35
```

Any thoughts and help appreciated.

Comment: Re: "I know there is a build in function to drop elements but it works if you wish to drop the last n elements. I want to drop the first n elements": I'm missing something. According to https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.drop:VAL, `List.drop` drops the first *i* elements, which is exactly what you say you want?

Comment: Re: "it won't be compiled. The error message I get is : `uncaught exception Subscription`": This is contradictory. If you're getting an uncaught exception when your code runs, then that means your code *did* compile successfully. (Your code can't be run until after it's been compiled.)

Comment: `if counter < n then` is the same as `if 0 < n then`.

Comment: The built-in `drop` really does drop (i.e. discard or remove) the first elements. The built-in function you're looking for is `take`.

Comment: Your final clause is essentially `drop (h::x,n) = h::drop(x,n)`. (You don't need an external counter – `n` is your counter – and `let` is not an assignment. You should probably review the basics of SML again.)

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the meaning of a `val` declaration.  It does
not declare a variable of which you can change the content afterwards
as in imperative programming languages.  Basically:

- as mentioned by @kopec, your test `if(counter < n)` is pointless
  since it reduces to `if(0 < n)` as `counter` as been set to 0, i.e.,
  the `val counter = counter + 1` placed after has no effect on that
  test
- the declaration `val counter = counter + 1` is useless.  It
  basically means "now `counters` is set to `counters + 1` (so 1) *only* in
  the `in ... end` block following" where it's not used at all.

Your code is thus equivalent to:

```ml
exception Subscription;

val counter = 0;

fun drop (l,0) = l 
| drop([], n) = raise Subscription
| drop(h::x, n) = if n<0 then raise Subscription
 else if(0 <n) then (h:: drop(x,n))
 else nil
 ;    

drop([1,2,3,4],2);
```

Hence, it's clear that with your example list you'll keep performing
recursive call (`(h:: drop(x,n))`) until reaching the third clause of
your function that raises the exception.

In this kind of situation, a proper way to solve your problem is to
use the arguments of your recursive function:

```ml
exception Subscription;

fun drop(l, 0) = l 
|   drop([], n) = raise Subscription
|   drop(h :: x, n) =
   if n < 0 then raise Subscription
   else (h :: drop(x, n - 1)) 
 ;

drop([1,2,3,4],2);
```

Hence, if `n` is greater or equal to the length of the input list, you
will eventually fall in the first clause of the function.

(Happy to see that you are getting familiar with pattern matching :))